# Document similarity- Odd one out

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, information-retrieval

Lets say I have "n" number of documents over a specific topic giving certain details. I want to get those documents who are not similar to the majority of the documents. As vague as this might seem, I know how to find cosine similarity between 2 documents. But lets say, I "know" I have 10 documents that are similar to each other, I introduce an 11th document and I need a way to judge how similar is this document with those 10 collectively and not just with every individual document.

I am working with scikit learn, so an answer or technique with its reference will help!

Comment: did my answer help you? if yes, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Represent each document as a `bag of words` and use `tf-idf` weight to represent a word in a particular document. Then compute cosine similarity with all `n` documents. Sum all similarity values and then normalize (divide the final sim value by `n`). It should give you a reasonable similarity between the `n` documents and your target document.

You can also consider [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) ([sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score.html)), [KL-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) to measure similarity/difference between two documents. Note that if you want to use them, you need to represent documents as a probability distribution. To compute probability of a term in a document, you can simply use the following formula:

```
Probability(w) = TF(w) / TTF(w)
```

where,

```
TF(w) = term frequency of word, w in a document, d
TTF(w) = total term frequency of word, w [sum of tf in all documents]
```

I believe any one of them will give you reasonable idea about similarity/dissimilarity between the `n` documents and your target document.